# Free online resources for beginner course

Tags: resource, learning

Along the lines of [the same question on French Language & Usage](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/509/free-online-resources-for-beginner-course), what are good, free online resources for an English-speaker to learn German properly from scratch?

Ideally, important areas such as grammar, vocabulary and pronunciation should be covered, to the point where a self-learner can start to read, write, listen to and speak simple German, firstly for use in everyday life and work, and thereafter be able to advance to a higher level with a strong foundation.

Comment: With "online resources" do you mean free?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try the [Deutsche Welle](http://www.dw-world.de/dw/0,,2547,00.html) resources. There's a [free 30-lection course](http://deutschkurse.dw-world.de/KursPlattform/WebObjects/KursPlattform.woa/wa/UAAuthDA/auth?par=G5n9P3ePUIqm93qsNXWNH45V0) going from A1 to B1. In addition, there's a ton of resources for all levels up to C1.

Answer (score 10):

Try [Babble](http://babbel.com), it's extremely useful for beginners. You'll learn basic knowledge of German, plus it's as user-friendly as possible cause it's designed by flash. To start learning, finding a dynamic website is very important, as I experienced.

Comment: This is *not* a free resource. In fact, one has to committed to periodic (monthly/quarterly/ etc) payments.

Comment: @gphilip: You could invite your friends and get a free week of it. More people you invite, more free weeks you get. right, It's *potentially* free.

Comment: I just finish the beginner's course 1. 
I actually liked it a lot. I think it's worth it.

Answer (score 3):

http://german.about.com/

lots of free stuff in different formats