# How can I start to use German language in daily life (with the help of a dictionary - for vocabulary)?

Tags: learning

I just start learning German along with some friends and I -personally- feel it would be better to use it everyday so that I get the hang of the rules in German. I am willing to keep a pocket dictionary with myself. I live in India and nobody speaks German but I want to start speaking some useful sentences everyday to a native German speaker.

So, what is the bare minimum I need to know about German - like nouns, verbs, etc. - that can help me achieve it? 
And is my strategy good, or should I tweak it to learn German  successfully, for example, if it's not focusing too much on vocabulary.

Also, and very important, where can I actually find people to converse with in German?

Comment: see also these questions http://german.stackexchange.com/q/944/23 and http://german.stackexchange.com/q/2040/23

Comment: Yeah thanks! I read both these questions and incidently both are marked favourites. But still they don't address the actual point at which I should be able to converse in German. I am already taking a German course in college but they are too slow and I am too impatient.

Comment: Also, I am trying to find the exact matter that a beginner should focus on.

Comment: @AnuragKalia: You seem to be asking at least three questions in this post. Please narrow it down and ask each one in a separate post. As Takkat noted, some of them have already been covered.

Comment: Ah, so that's the problem! And I think I know my problem better now. I shall be asking another question for it. Thanks for showing me the light! :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you plan to study the German Language an qualify in some way (become a translator or so) or if you want to be able travel through Germany and talk with the people.

If your aim is to be able to communicate I think you can find valuable resources when you google for

> Deutsch für Ausländer online

or

> Deutsch als Fremdsparche

Start focusing on words like

> gratis (= free of charge )

to avoid expensive sites.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to go the same route as you, minus the college course.  I think the key is to look around for communities on the internet that are multilingual.  This site has a chat feature that I haven't explored, and live mocha also has a chat feature.  Finding an irc chat room about a subject that interests you and has a high population of german speakers is another option i am going to explore.  I plan on finding some "young reader" literature in german as well.  Ultimately i would like to find fluent german speakers willing to chat over some voip system, but I am not at that level yet, so i haven't gone looking yet.