# Can someone point me to an easy resource that teaches the German language?

Tags: learning, book

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free online resources for beginner course](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/944/free-online-resources-for-beginner-course)

Can someone point me to an easy resource that teaches the German language?

Keep in mind that I'm totally ignorant in German. I'm not looking for a dictionary as I don't know anything in German yet.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2040/what-is-a-good-way-to-start-learning-german

Comment: Do you think german for dummies/idiots is a good book for learning the basics?

Comment: I didn't read it, but I guess, that it wouldn't be a too bad start.

Comment: I want to be fluent in German .I've got a job opportunity at a german hospital and they require fluency in german.

Comment: on an unrelated note: fluency takes time. everyone wants to be fluent. If you want it fast you had better sit down and start studying with good resources rather than easy ones.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on *how quick* (okay, you said it already: quick) and *how good* you want to learn. Not to forget how you want to learn in general.

I've heard that [Livemocha](http://livemocha.com) and [Babbel](http://babbel.com) are very good for learning online. However, if you have the time and the possibility, just grab someone who can talk German and just talk with him. Also watch German movies/listen to something in German, that really helps. (I learned French that way :))