# How should an Indian start learning German whose primary language is not English?

Tags: learning

I am an Indian and my primary language is Hindi. English is our secondary language, which we use in college studies and corporate offices.
Our daily communications happens through Hindi and our local languages.

My goal is to learn a basic level of German that will help me managing normal conversations.
I am a working person who does not have any access to a teacher or contacts who know German. I can invest time in self-learning on weekends.

Considering these points, where should I **start learning German**?

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE. As it stands, your question is extremely broad. Can you please [edit] it to specify: 1) What are your goals? Do you want to focus on some aspect of the language? 2) What resources (such as native speakers, teachers) do you have access to? 3) How much time and energy are you willing to invest? — Also note that if your question is not specific to learning German, it may be better suited for [languagelearning.se], but you still need to clarify these things.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I've updated my question. Sorry for immaturely formed question

Comment: No worries, thanks for editing. I reopened your question for now as it is not blatantly too broad anymore. Be aware that the community may still consider it too broad. If you have any further detail to narrow down your question, feel free to add them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better asked on [languagelearning.SE].

Comment: @Jan: “because it is better asked on X” is not a valid close reason. For closing, the only thing that matters is whether the question is off-topic here. Questions can be on-topic on multiple sites.

Comment: Here there are some lists of resources: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/944/free-online-resources-for-beginner-course and http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Fair enough. I still consider the question off-topic here, as it is more about learning the language from scratch than about its finer points. I should probably have phrased the comment better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have an institute called Goethe who's job is to "spread" the German language.

They also have an Indian branch.

I'd suggest you start there.

https://www.goethe.de/ins/in/en/index.html?wt_sc=india

They also have online courses available:

https://www.goethe.de/ins/in/en/spr/kur/fer.html

If that is too complicated you can always go with:

http://www.rosettastone.com - paid

or

https://www.duolingo.com - free

Both offer language independent modalities for acquiring a new foreign language and have German courses.

I personally have used Rosetta Stone for Spanish and can recommend it.

Comment: I added a link to the online courses offered by the Goethe Institute. I thought you'd be able to find it yourself.